# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException with JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I try to link a library.so to a java IHM and i'm a bit struggling with the array 
I made the .so by myself in c++ so let's see what's in there
.h

```
class WestgardInterface {

private:

/*ATTRIBUTS*/
/** WestgardInterface instance*/
static WestgardInterface *ms_instance;

protected:
WestgardInterface();

public:
/*DESTRUCTOR*/
~WestgardInterface();
static WestgardInterface *getInstance();
void WGevaluateWithListOnly( Measure m[], float mean, float sd);
};

extern "C" void WGevaluateWithListOnly( Measure m[], float mean, float sd){
WestgardInterface* lib = WestgardInterface::getInstance();
return lib->WGevaluateWithListOnly( m, mean, sd);
}
```

then there is my cpp file

```
WestgardInterface *WestgardInterface::ms_instance = nullptr;

WestgardInterface::WestgardInterface(){}

WestgardInterface::~WestgardInterface() {}

WestgardInterface *WestgardInterface::getInstance(){
    if (nullptr == ms_instance)
    {
        ms_instance =  new WestgardInterface();
    }
    return ms_instance;
 } 

 void WestgardInterface::WGevaluateWithListOnly(Measure m[], float mean, float sd) {
cout<<"mean "<<mean<<endl<<"sd "<<sd;
}
```

you can see i'm not even using the array in my c++ code thats why i think the problem should be in the java part

```
public class Westgard {
static {       
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path","../logic/resources/calculator");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WGInputs.ByValue jnaInputs [] = (WGInputs.ByValue[])new WGInputs.ByValue().toArray(2);
    WGInputs.ByValue input = new WGInputs.ByValue();
    Measure.ByValue m = new Measure.ByValue();
    m.valeur = 18;
    Date.ByValue d = new Date.ByValue();
    d.m_day = 10;
    d.m_month = 10;
    d.m_year = 10;
    d.m_hour = 12;
    d.m_min = 12;
    d.m_sec = 12;
    m.date = d;
    input.m = m;
    jnaInputs[0] = input;
    jnaInputs[1] = input;
    InterfaceLibWestgard.INSTANCE.WGevaluateWithListOnly(jnaInputs, 12, 1);
}
}
```

then when i try to execute it i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=32, offset=64
at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:185)
at com.sun.jna.Memory.share(Memory.java:114)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1434)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.toArray(Structure.java:1453)
at p65.logic.westgard.Westgard.main(Westgard.java:12)
```

I know this come from my array because if the size's array down to 1 it works so would like to know how i should declare my array in the java code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a problem with 32/64 bit System comapbility. Please look if your JDK,DLL and DLL dependecies are 32/64 bit. I had the same problem few days ago.

Comment: i'm afraid this is not the same issue  everything is 64 bits               
java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)     file libuntitled.so.0.1 
libuntitled.so.0.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xa9388f7ab8a0618f5a3a58a8b5ef8c070917ac08, not stripped